# DOMRect Properties not Enumerable because they don't inherit from the same prototype as an Object. Why?

Tags: javascript

I know that DOMRect properties are inherited from the DOMRectPrototype and therefore cannot be accessed by Object.assign and Object.keys, therefore making DOMRect properties not enumerable. My question is, what is the reason for doing this?

I have a function that compares whether two objects are equal and I want to run 2 instances of `document.body.getBoundingClientRect()` through it. How would I define an enumerable get property on the prototype? I tried this:

```
const rect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
Object.defineProperty(rect, "b", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return rect }});
Object.keys(rect)
```

but no luck, it gives the DOMRect property back as a single object

Comment: Probably because its properties are getter/setter functions, so that e.g when you set `DOMRectInstance.width`, its `right` property is updated.

Comment: Is there anyway to make their properties enumerable by defining a property on them?

Comment: @Thomas That will shadow the setters/getters. BTW, why do you need this? Show us the real problem!

Comment: I want to make a decision based on whether or not some domrect value has changed @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir what's the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm not following you. Could you elaborate on that and probably add an example to your question?

Comment: @Kaiido how does that behavior preclude enumerability though?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I have a function that comapres whether two objects are equal and I want to run 2 instances of document.body.getBoundingClientRect() through it. How would I define an enumerable get property on the prototype?

I tried this: `const rect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(); Object.defineProperty(rect, "b", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return rect }}); Object.keys(rect)` but no luck, it gives the DOMRect property back as a single object

Comment: @AluanHaddad that's a decision that the ones who wrote the specs had to take, that's why I started my comment, which btw is just a comment, with "*Probably*". The extended logic I can see from this is that these getter setter are attached to the prototype itself, so that the internal methods of every DOMRect instance are all the same exact functions, working over different private variables. They could probably just as well have made it enumerable, but they didn't, just like for the majority of every other built-in DOM-API's property.

Comment: @Thomas, If all you need is a way to iterate over these keys, why don't you simply hard-code it? `isSameRect = (r1,r2) => !['x', 'y', 'left', 'top', 'right', 'bottom', 'width', 'height'].some(k => r1[k]!== r2[k]);`

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for clarifying. I just wanted to point out that all of that works equally if the property is defined on each object. More memory is consumed which might be the reason but I'm inclined to think that DOM APIs are just badly designed

Answer (score 0):

While I do not encourage this, to answer your question:

```
function copyDOMRect(input) {
    return {
        x: input.x,
        y: input.y,
        left: input.left,
        right: input.right,
        top: input.top,
        bottom: input.bottom,
        height: input.height,
        width: input.width,
    };
}

copyDOMRect(new DOMRect(0,0,100,100)); // now you can use Object.keys, etc.
```

You can also modify the prototype of DOMRect (also discouraged) to make this simpler.

Comment: Anyway I can just define a property on the prototype that will give me the values back as an enumerable?

Comment: No, you can only define a property on the prototype that does what `copyDOMRect` does, e.g. DOMRect.prototype.toObj`